# How to create dependent dropdowns in a cq5 dialog

Tags: javascript, jsp, dialog, aem

I am developing a component for Communiqué 5 (CQ5, now AEM) using JSP, HTML and JavaScript; and I found some trouble when trying to create two dropdowns for which the values of the second one will depend on the values on the first one.

In the component dialog (dialog.xml) I have two `select` similar to these ones (simplified for clarity):

```xml
...
<type
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        defaultValue="Dark"
        fieldLabel="Color Type"
        name="./type"
        type="select"
        xtype="selection">
    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <o1
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Dark"
                value="dark"/>
        <o2
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Light"
                value="light"/>
    </options>
</tipo>
<color
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        defaultValue="dark-blue"
        fieldLabel="Color"
        name="./color"
        type="select"
        xtype="selection">
    <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <o1
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Dark Blue"
                value="dark-blue"/>
        <o2
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Light Blue"
                value="light-blue"/>
        <o3
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Dark Green"
                value="dark-green"/>
        <o4
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Light Green"
                value="light-green"/>
        <o5
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Dark Red"
                value="dark-red"/>
    </options>
</color>
...
```

That generates two dropdowns in the dialog:

- the first one with the color type (dark or light); and
- the second one with colors (dark and light blue, dark and light green, and dark red)

Something like this image:

[image: dialog box]

How can I make the values of the second dropdown (colors) "update" depending on the value of the first dropdown (color type)? For example, if the color type is "dark" I only want to see dark colors: dark blue, dark green, dark red; and similarly, if the color type is "light" I want to see only light colors: light blue and light green.

I initially thought about doing this with JavaScript, adding a `selectionChanged` listener to the first dropdown that would show/hide the options in the second list. But I couldn't find any relation between the field and the `div` with the options (the generated code is not an HTML `select` but a separate CQ5 structure with `div`s and hidden inputs).

Then I thought about having different dropdown lists for the second option: one with light colors and the other with dark colors, and directly show/hide the whole dropdown list instead of some options. Something that I could do by assigning `id`/`cls` to the selection widget, but it complicates the logic behind and it is difficult to maintain (if I add new options, I'd need to create new dropdowns, and in my real code I have more than 2 options but 6).

How can I create to dropdowns in which the options in the second one depend on the option selected in the first one?

<sub>[Cross-post from StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3445/c%C3%B3mo-crear-listas-desplegables-dependientes-en-cq5-aem).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like:

- add property "id" with value like "colorsComp" for your selections with colors.
- instead of nodes-options use optionsProvider for you component with colors:

  ```
  function(path, record) {
      return [{
          text:"Dark Blue",
          value:"dark-blue"
      },{
          text:"Light Blue",
          value:"light-blue"
      },{
          text:"Dark Green",
          value:"dark-green"
      },{
          text:"Light Green",
          value:"light-green"
      },{
          text:"Dark Red",
          value:"dark-red"
      }];
  }
  ```
- then for your "color type" widget you can filter that options regarding type. Callback for event `selectionChanged` can look like:

  ```
  function(comp,value,checked){
      var colorsDropDown = CQ.Ext.getCmp("colorsComp");
      if (!colorsDropDown.original) {
          colorsDropDown.original = colorsDropDown.optionsProvider;
      }

      colorsDropDown.optionsProvider = function(path, record) {
          return colorsDropDown.original().filter(function (el) {
              return el.value.indexOf(value) != -1;
          });
      }

      colorsDropDown.setOptions(colorsDropDown.optionsProvider());
  }
  ```

There we get our "colors" widget by id, we set, then we save our original provider, set new, with filtering and also update available options.

It's somewhat dirty solution, but I hope, that it will give you some insight.

**Upd1:** you also need to do similar manipulation on component initialization, to show correctly filtered options when widget first shown.

Comment: I will try this one and let you know how it worked. It looks promising. Thanks

Comment: This helped me a lot, and was able to figure it out following the steps indicated in here

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the solution @Alex has provided, From maintainability and scalability perspective i can think of 2 options.

**one solution** could be to maintain the list of options in the second dropdown as sling osgi config. From the component dialog you can make a sling servlet call with required parameter(dark, light). The servlet would then parse the config, construct json and render the second drop down.

Just a thought, you could store the config values this way -> dark=dark brown; light=light brown; etc, which will help you match the values in config based on the request parameter.

[image]

**Second solution:**
You can also drive this logic through a component which will accept key value pairs of colors. If you have a admin page of some sort in your application, authors can author the list of colors using some governance, your code can then read from this component and render the second drop down.